# how to download an uploaded file in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

am creating an option to download a file (pdf) uploaded.just through searching i have across with some instruction (a view) and (url) ,when i try to pass the named url to my template i get this error `Reverse for 'download' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['download/(?P<filepath>[^/]+)/$']`
Just i cant figure a way to download the file.what i want to achieve is that once a download button is place should open a new tab and preview the file and give an option to print or download the file(pdf) using the chrome features.[image: see the photo]

here are the codes

### views.py

```python
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

def download(request, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

### models.py

```python
class Cv(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='cv')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename
```

### urls.py

```python
    path('download/<str:filepath>/', views.download, name="download"),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

### template

```html
 <a href="{% url 'download' %}" class="btn btn-fill wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.8s" data-wow-delay="0.4s">Downlaod <i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```

help please

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there!

Just one step is missing: you need to pass the download path in the view where you render the template as a variable and use it in the template where you render the download button as follows.

View:

```py
  # view to show the download page
  def request_dwonload(self, request):
     # determine the downoad file path
     filepath = "...."
     # render the download template 
     return render(request, 'download.html', {'filepath': filepath})
```

Add parameter `filepath` in template `download.html`:

```html
 <a href="{% url 'download' filepath %}" class="btn btn-fill wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.8s" data-wow-delay="0.4s">Downlaod <i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```

Also not that you named the path paramater `filepath` in your urls definition, so you should change hour download view accordingy:

```py
def download(request, filepath):
    # etc...
```

Comment: is it necessary to have another function means the download function wont do alone

Comment: You could use the same view function 'download' to handle for instance POST and GET requests diffeerently, similar to how Form processing functions work. Or make the filepath parameter optional (e.g. default None) and create two different urls, onw eith and one without the str parameter

Comment: am still getting the error NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'download' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['download/(?P<filepath>[^/]+)/$']

Comment: how exactly should i format the request_dwonload function because my file is in http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/cv/file.pdf